# Can I use OLS with robust standard errors to analyze proportions?

Tags: least-squares, proportion

I have a response variable that is a proportion. It is not the outcome of a series of Bernoulli trials, so there is no numerator/denominator, just the proportion. I'd like to assess the relationship between this response and several explanatory variables.

Proportions are bounded in the closed interval [0, 1]. I have read that this means the cumulative PDF will be sigmoidal, and the variance will be heteroscedastic (more variable nearer to 0.5, less variable nearer to 0 and 1).

I know some people advocate using beta regression in this situation, or logit transforming the response, but both of these options are unsatisfying since they require adjustments to observations at 0 and 1. There is also the fractional logit model and the zero/one inflated beta model (see comments), which have the advantage that they can both use data in [0, 1].

I am wondering if there is another option. Using an OLS model is often frowned upon for proportions, as it can yield predictions outside of [0, 1] and homoscedasticity assumptions may not be met.

**However, given that my goal is simply to interpret the coefficients from my model, not to make predictions, I have two questions:**

**1) Providing I calculate standard errors that are robust to heteroscedasticity, is an OLS model a reasonable course of action?**

**2) Does the fact that the response is bounded between [0, 1] in some way bias estimates of the coefficients?**

Edit: just to clarify, I have a situation where observations are fairly evenly distributed within [0, 1], with many between [0, 0.25) and (0.75, 1]. Therefore they are not just on the linear part of the sigmoidal slope.

Comment: There is at least one problems with using robust regression: the effect of explanatory variables tends to be non-linear, but OLS will not give you that. Can you clarify what the source of the boundary points is?

Comment: "*unsatisfying since they require adjustments to observations at 0 and 1*" -- there's always 0/1-inflated beta.

Comment: Suppose we regress proportion $y$ against a single explanatory $x$. Even if the relationship is monotonically increasing, so you expect slope above zero, you'd find with a linear model that the estimated slope tends to zero as you widen the range of $x$ values that you observe over. On the other hand if your observations are only taken over a narrow part of the sigmoid, the estimated slope will be similar to the slope of that section. What would be the "right" slope that you're trying to estimate and what would it mean?

Comment: @Silverfish: thank you, that is insightful. I will run some simulations to convince myself of this. Very helpful.

Comment: You may want to examine references in ecological regression, which use the technique you describe frequently.  See for example, Cross-Level Inference by Chris Achen for pros and cons of the approach or the other references given here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecological_regression.